# Get redirected page contents of MYOB login

Tags: .net, authentication, redirect, myob

I am building a web API to communicate with MYOB website and site contents. Through a generated URL containing the client id and the key, I can open the login page. After successful login, I receive a security code through email which I have to type into the new authentication page. If the code is right then I am redirected to a page which gives me a code to access the site contents.
I have used `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(redirectUrl);` which opens the login page and I can do all the process manually. But I need my code to take care of all the process. So I used HttpClient as below:

```
      public static Task<string> GetCode(string url)
    {
        try
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);                
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
                new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("text/plain"));
            HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("authorize").Result;
            return response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();                    
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return null;                
        }
    }
```

The code only returns Not found error.